# difference between baby carriage and a stroller

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between baby carriage and a stroller?

Is it the same thing?

hypothesis: there is a difference in the baby's position, baby carriage is for lying position while stroller is for sitting position

stroller is this: http://demandware.edgesuite.net/sits_pod22/dw/image/v2/AAMT_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-chicco_catalog/default/dw44ea9e7a/images/products/Gear_Sept2015/TRE/Tre_Titan_Hi.jpg?sw=1200&sh=1200&sm=fit

while baby carriage is this: http://cdn.trendhunterstatic.com/thumbs/luxury-baby-carriage.jpeg

Am I right? What is the difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_transport) broadly agrees with you. In baby carriages or prams, the baby is usually lying down and facing the parent. In push chairs or strollers, they are usually sitting up and facing forwards.